# Vaadin 8 licensing error for vaadin charts

Tags: charts, vaadin, runtimeexception, license-key

I have a vaadin 8 application that builds and runs fine with versions up to 8.14.3. along with a vaadin pro subscription. Since 8.15 and the change in to CVDLv4 the application builds but doesn't run.

I have installed the license for vaadin charts and it is recognized, as I get: "Vaadin Charts 4 registered to ### (Pro Tools subscription)" during build. If i remove the license file compile fails as expected. I've also tried the license as a parameter with the same results.

When I run the application (on Netbeans), I get: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to validate subscription". I thought subscription validation was only done during the build. In any case it should be able to validate the license as it did during the build. I've tried all the suggestions I could find (firewall, adblocker etc are off), tried different browsers etc. but couldn't get it to run.

Comment: Vaadin 8.15 needs a license by itself - could it be possible that you are missing that license?

Comment: You're probably right. It seems the extended support needs a prime or enterprise subscription and I only have a pro. Thanks.

Comment: give a try on https://vaadin.com/directory/component/apexchartsjs  apexcharts which is a vaadin addon at free of cost, go through the examples in the link

Answer (score 1):

Vaadin 8.14.3 is the last release under Apache 2 license. The subsequent releases are offered under [commercial extended maintenance](https://vaadin.com/vaadin-8-extended-maintenance).