# After migrating from free Vaadin 7 to Vaadin 8, licence is required?

Tags: vaadin7, vaadin8

I am migrating a Java 7 project that makes use of Vaadin 7 to Java 11 and Vaadin 8.

With Java 7/Vaadin 7 the project was using the following Vaadin libs:
[Vaddin7 modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL5YD.png)

For the migration we followed the guide described here: https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/migration/migrating-to-vaadin8
However, after deploying I had the surprise that Vaadin is asking for license as I can understand
from this exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:588)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:583)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:582)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Desktop.isDesktopSupported(Desktop.java:328)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop(Desktop.java:302)
        at com.vaadin.pro.licensechecker.SystemBrowser.open(SystemBrowser.java:27)
        at com.vaadin.pro.licensechecker.VaadinComIntegration.openBrowserAndWaitForKey(VaadinComIntegration.java:26)
        at com.vaadin.pro.licensechecker.LicenseChecker.checkLicense(LicenseChecker.java:56)
        at com.vaadin.pro.licensechecker.LicenseChecker.checkLicense(LicenseChecker.java:36)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServletService.verifyLicense(VaadinServletService.java:67)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServletService.<init>(VaadinServletService.java:49)
        at com.vaadin.spring.server.SpringVaadinServletService.<init>(SpringVaadinServletService.java:56)
        at com.vaadin.spring.server.SpringVaadinServlet.createServletService(SpringVaadinServlet.java:150)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.createServletService(VaadinServlet.java:396)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.init(VaadinServlet.java:226)
```

The project is not using any of the commercial add-ons, so I need further guidance on how to migrate to Vaadin 8 free edition.

Comment: The last free edition is 8.14.3, check this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/73065963/8962195

Comment: Thanks. They should make this statement more visible on their website.